# how to implement rmse(root mean square error)

Tags: python, arrays, function, dataset, computer-science

I am implementing rmse for iris dataset when I am trying to calculate y_pred it gives an error.

```
def fmodel(x):
    s=np.linspace(0,0,10)
    for i in range (len(x)):
        for j in range(1):
            s[i]=x[i][j]+x[i][j+1]+x[i][j+2]+x[i][j+3]
    return s
```

fmodel is function for calculating `y_pred`. Which produce error
invalid index to scalar variable.
at line

```
s[i]=x[i][j]+x[i][j+1]+x[i][j+2]+x[i][j+3]
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing i can understand from the error is that you are trying to assign an index to a scalar value...in this case **s** is a numpy array so the only problem lies in **x**, try to check if **x** is actually a 2D array. Then another thing, if you are trying to solve the classification problem it makes no sense to use the rmse as a loss function you should use the cross entropy instead as you are not trying to minimize the euclidean distance between the predicted value and the true value.

Comment: In x I have iris dataset and basically I m trying to perform feature selection using differential evolution algorithm. that's why I m using rmse function as fitness function.Would it be right choice to use it for fitness?i don't have any idea about it because I am new in python

Comment: another error could be due to less than 4 elements in each row of x since it looks at [j] to [j+3], with j set at 0